# How to test internet speed using terminal emulator on Android

Tags: linux, networking, command-line

I have Termux app installed on my Android phone. Is there a speed test tool that I can install and use from the command line? I have tried `speedtest-cli`, installed it by:

`pip install speedtest-cli`
`pip install speedtest-cli --upgrade`

I also have `python` installed.

When trying to use `speedtest-cli` it gives me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speedtest.py", line 1401, in shell
    speedtest = Speedtest()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speedtest.py", line 743, in _init_
    self.get_config()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speedtest.py", line 765, in get_config
    raise ConfigRetrievalError(e)
speedtest.ConfigRetrievalError: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/speedtest-cli", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speedtest.py", line 1498, in main
    shell()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speedtest.py", line 1402, in shell
    except (ConfigRetrievalError, HTTP_ERRORS):
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

How do I get a working command-line speedtest tool in Android and Termux?

Answer (score 2):

We can run an script called `speedtest.py`  localized in [Github](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/blob/master/speedtest.py)

`python speedtest.py`

Comment: I'm trying to place that script inside the python working directory `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python` but it turns out I can't access it unless I root my phone (Nougat). Is there a way to set an external python path outside the termux directory?